# how to maintain date input field size with same size of other fields in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make same input size for all fields in all the cases: XS,SM,LG etc using bootstrap.However,all the fields maintains same size except for **Sanction Date** field.

here is the image below:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Record Loan Type Information</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">  
  <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script> <!-- bootstrap-datetimepicker requires Moment.js to be loaded first -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format:"DD/MM/YYYY", useCurrent: false });
        });         
 </script>

<style>
 body {
  background-color: #584F39;
}
.panel.panel-primary {
  border-color: #73AD21;
}
.panel-group .panel .panel-heading {
  background: #73AD21;
}
.form-horizontal .panel.panel-primary {
  border-color: #73AD21;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .form-group-top {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
}
</style>


</head>
<body >

<div class="container"  >  
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-primary"  >
            <div class="panel-heading" >
                <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">Record Loan Type Information</h3>       
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">

                <form class="form-horizontal" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="acode">Loan ID:</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-8">
                             <div class="input-group">                                             
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="acode"  placeholder="Enter Loan ID">            
                             </div>
                         </div>
                        </div>              

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;" >Loan Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">                                 
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Loan Name" >         
                                </div>
                            </div>      
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="dcode">Description:</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-8">
                             <div class="input-group">                                             
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dcode"  placeholder="Enter Loan Description">               
                             </div>
                         </div>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Amount:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">                                 
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Amount" >        
                                </div>
                            </div>      
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;" >Sanction Date:</label>
                           <div class="col-sm-3">
                               <div class="input-group date">
                                   <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span> 
                                   <input type="text"  id='datetimepicker1' class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">     
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Interest Rate:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">                                 
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Rate" >          
                                </div>
                            </div>      
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group">        
                          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Exit</button> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

please help to on fixing this.thanks

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: thanks @Raviteja .But i don't have fiddle account.

Comment: you don't need an account to make a fiddle

Comment: thanks @Raviteja . this the link  https://jsfiddle.net/sfrf6g7j/                                  however it is not preserving the correct bootstrap display that i have on my local pc.take a look thanks

Comment: It is fine in the fiddle. What's wrong ?

Comment: thanks @Raviteja.i have add an image on the post showing the display size problem of field Sanction date  marked in red line.thanks

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/sfrf6g7j/1/) okay ?

Comment: thanks @Raviteja. yes screen is similar to that one.But still you can see date field is still little bigger.

Comment: you mean in fiddle ? Or In your local machine ?

Comment: thanks @Raviteja. i did what you suggest #datetimepicker1{
  width:159px;
} but date field box  is still little bit unequal size comparing with others.Any way, setting width  manually , is it good practice.I don't know much  about it.if so then i just have to decrease the width size little bit and done.thanks

Comment: It is very fine.Because you need the same size for all types of devices.Only this(manually setting) could do as `form-control` causes this(your problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your custom CSS.

You need to fix the width of input for datetimepicker

```
#datetimepicker1{
  width:159px;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Raviteja. your comments give me very nice & clear explanation.Thank you.

Comment: This is against Bootstrap best practises